# How to record actions using JMeter, using wired connection?

Tags: jmeter

I have followed most of the JMeter tutorials, but there's one thing that prevents me from testing our app specially iOS. I can't be in one network. We have a separate network for both Mobile and Desktop/Laptop. Is there any way that I can record JMeter using Wired Connection, instead of WiFi? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use JMeter for recording mobile device activity you could go for [USB Tethering](https://www.wikihow.com/Share-Your-iPhone-Internet-Connection-With-Your-PC#Using_USB_Tethering_sub), this way your computer becomes connected to the iOS device network hence JMeter should be able to capture the traffic.

An easier option would be going for [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285377-Recording-Using-Apple-Devices), as a bonus you will have possibility to export recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of the dynamic parameters.

Comment: I tried the USB Tethering but I was wondering where to enter my proxy settings

Comment: On the mobile device

Comment: I'm sorry.. I'm very new to doing this and the iPhone. I cannot see where I could enter the proxy settings on the USB